# Django проблема в коде аутентификации

Tags: python, django

Я хочу сделать сайт только для зарегистрированных пользователей.
Для этого я прописал url, по которым сайт будет перенаправлять всех не пошедших аутентификацию пользователей. В папке settings.py моего проекта прописал следующие строчки:

```
LOGIN_URL="/login/"
LOGOUT_URL="/logout/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL="/"
```

В файле url.py проекта прописал:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin, auth


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', auth.views.login),
    url(r'^', include("polls.urls")),
]
```

В файле views.py приложения:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from polls.models import piple
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

@login_required
def add_piple(request):
    if request.POST:
        person=piple(name=request.POST.get("person_name"), number=request.POST.get("person_number"))
        person.save()
        return render(request,"add.html")

@login_required
def list_piple(request):
    persons = piple.objects.all()
    ctx={"persons":persons}
    return render(request,"list.html",ctx)

@login_required
def delete(request, poll_id):
    piple.objects.filter(id=poll_id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/list/")

@login_required
def update(request,poll_id):
    return 0
```

---

После запуска выдаёт следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В чём проблема? Всё делал в соответствии с книгой Дронов В.А django практика создания web-сайтов на python. Страница 243

Comment: Попробуйте `import django.contrib.auth.views` после других импортов в urls.py

Comment: А вообще книга Дронова написана под очень старую версию Django, рекомендую найти литературу посвежее, например, [официальную документацию](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/)

Comment: Или поставить соответствующую версию django, и попробовать на ней :) Но это плохое решение.